# VSE: How to crop specific segment of a video?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I'm dealing with a 1080p workspace and 1080p video footage.
I need a segment where I crop the segment of a specific strip so its just of the girl in the picture below.

So going from picture one...
[image]

...To Picture 2 (assume the background is transparent).
[image]

How do I do this in the VSE for a video? Using 'crop' in the strip menue scales the image rather than cuts parts out of it. And the transform effect strip doesn't have any options other than zoom in (I don't want to zoom in...I want to crop the video and display it in the 1080p workspace like the 2nd image is, then I'd put other images to the side of it etc).

To Date I've been placing colour strips overtop to make it cropped the way I want (would be 2 white strips in this case if I did id that way), but this is alot of micromanagement when I need to do alot of this stuff in 1 frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [VSE_Transform_Tools](https://github.com/doakey3/VSE_Transform_Tools) addon does just what you're looking for.

The in-house method is to enable "Image Offset" and adjust the values in the "Image Crop" section, then reposition the cropped image using the values in the image offset area:

[image]

Comment: Assuming that is true, that would solve the issue. I don't necessarily feel comfy downloading third party addons though. I feel okay downloading stuff that comes up in blender's addon lists, but I don't know how the community works in terms of whether anything else is safe or not. Does anyone know an inhouse method that works, or where can I find confirmation if this is safe? I know you made it, just I don't have the information to determine what is safe practice here.

Comment: Since the code is open source and can be read by anyone, it would be pretty dumb for me to make it do anything malicious. The more people who star and download a repository, the more likely it is that the code is being read and reviewed by other people. That said, unless you can read the code yourself, it might be hard to verify if it's safe.

Comment: ya I cant read code like that. I'm just scared something weird might happen and screw up all my projects....which is kinda paranoid to some people but I get weird bugs already in blender. It wouldn't surprise me if a bug only I get interacts with something from a script and .....ya. lol. I'm in the middle of a project is all, risking potential weird stuff would not be good right now...and I don't have experience with whether such scripts are foolproof or not with blender.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a safe method.

Comment: ah I see now. I didn't realize image offset had to be enabled. i was dealing with video footage rather than an image so i never thought to check it in combination with image crop.